# Picker not animated

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animated, uipicker

I've a problem with XCode.
If I make a Picker (DatePicker, PickerView, ...) he isn't animated on my MacBook Pro, but if I launch the project with another Mac it works.
I haven't any output in the console and the code works but the Picker is not animated.

Does anyone know what's wrong ?

Thx.

Comment: I have the exact same problem, pickers are scrolling for other people with same tools (Xcode 3.2.5) but not for me :-(

Comment: I've try with XCode 3.2.5 and the preview 6 but it doesn't work. The problem seems to be linked with my MacbookPro. :/